# errors while trying to remove non-UTF characters returned from a DLL

Tags: python, dll, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to fix one of the fields in a structure returned by a dll to not have any non UTF-8 characters.   When I try to modify the field I'm getting errors

```
import _portaudio as pa
...
my_dev_info = pa.get_device_info(device_index)
my_dev_info.name = my_dev_info.name.decode('utf-8','ignore')

    my_dev_info.name = my_dev_info.name.decode('utf-8','ignore')
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid c
    ontinuation byte
```

If I try to simply reassign .name to something else there is a different error

```
my_dev_info.name = '???'
AttributeError: Fields read-only: cannot modify values
```

pa is import from a dll I believe. I don't have control over its contents.  Any way around this?

This works fine with a simple string, but not with the 'pa' object :

```
>>> s='┼δⁿτΦ foo'
>>> s = s.decode('utf-8','ignore')
>>> s
u' foo'
>>>
```

Comment: Given that every Unicode character can be encoded in UTF-8, there's no such thing as a "non-UTF-8 character". If you're getting data in your stream which is invalid UTF-8, it sounds like you should check your assumption that it's *meant* to be UTF-8...

Comment: just a guess, according to Jon Skeet idea: since you are on Windows, try with latin1 (is it a Î char?)

Comment: While we're guessing, how about `cp1252` if you're on Windows? Or perhaps write out some of the data to a file and run it through: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet